# What should I call the process of converting an object to a string?

Tags: terminology, strings, semantics

We are having a game of 'semantic football' in the office over this matter: I am writing a method for an object which will represent the object as a string. That string should be such that when typed (more likely, cut and pasted) into the interpreter window (I will keep the language name out of this for now), will produce an object which is, for our purposes, identical to the one upon which the method was called. There is a spirited discussion over the 'best' name for this method.

The terms **pickle**, **serialize**, **deflate**, *etc* have been proposed. However, it seems that those terms assume some process for the de-pickling (unserialization, *etc*) that is not necessarily the language interpreter itself. That is, they do not specifically refer to the case where strings of valid code are produced. This is closer to a **quine**, but we are re-producing the object not the code, so this is not quite right.

any suggestions?

Comment: How about "stringify"? Since I don't think anyone I know uses this term, you can come up with your own semantics for it.

Comment: Isn't "ToString" the common function name for this in a few languages or is this slightly different than a few cases where I've seen this in my experience?

Comment: Your title screams ToString

Comment: I did not think 'ToString' created executable code strings. For example, it might drop quotes around strings, etc, but otherwise be unambiguous.

Comment: @shabbychef: If your object is `CodeGenerator`, having a `toString()` method for it fits semantically.

Comment: @Frustrated, there is a stringify concept (method?) for dealing with JSON objects.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: (+1) exactly the term that I actually do use for the object-to-string transformation (when I write one myself).  But I'm not usually concerned with the "unstringifying" side that seems important to OP.

Comment: `toString()` sounds more like a user(programmer?)-readable representation, for the program itself (reflection) or debugging.

Comment: I'd go with ToString or [Unbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Unboxing).

Comment: @Frustrated: "stringification" is used fairly often in the Perl community. It (and its root "stringify") is a very good word for the process of turning an object into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python that is the "repr()" function.  A string representation of the object.

Comment: Seems like a bad name to me. It tells me nothing about what it does.

Comment: @Alb: Take it up with the rest of the python community.  We all know it as `repr()` and we implement a special `__repr__` method in our class definitions to work with it.

Comment: @S.Lott Obviously you're not responsible for what it's called in python, but suggesting using a bad name just because it's used in python doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Alb: Here's the point.  What seems like a "bad" name when you first read it isn't a sound judgement.  The first time you encounter a name, it doesn't tell you much.  Indeed, most names don't pass the "tells me about what it does" test since most names don't expose every dependency, every side-effects and every possible exception.

Comment: I disagree about the when you first read it part of your comment. I would have no idea what a method called 'repr' might do on any object. Whereas when I look at, for example, ArrayList class in java (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if I wanted to do any of those operations, and read through the method list, I'd easily find the one I needed. They might not tell me exactly how it works, but at least I know which one to check out in more detail.

Comment: @Alb: Agreed.  You have no idea what any method really does.  You can guess from the Java docs because you have a pretty deep knowledge.  Read some of the ridiculous StackOverflow questions from folks who don't seem to be able to interpret the method names.  Your standard for "good" or "bad" doesn't have much impact on other people's ability to remember what it does or guess wisely.  Indeed, a surprising number of people look at the same methods you look at and guess very, very poorly.

Comment: @S.Lott Fair point bad and good names are relative and subjective. But I think it's clear that using actual words is at least a starting point. `trimToSize()` is more descriptive than `trm()` for example.

Comment: @Alb: "using actual words is at least a starting point".  It can be a starting point.  I had a student argue with me -- at length -- that the Unix `rm` command was absolutely useless and "remove" was the most unnatural possible word for removing a file from the file system and he felt that this "unix" thing was oversold because of that name.  Starting with words may be a good idea.  But prior art and convention seem to count for more than words.

Comment: @S.Lott I don't like a lot of unix command names either for the same reasons. In search of a good answer to this I've created a specific question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/46894/13825

Comment: @Alb: Liking them or not liking them doesn't matter.  A judgement of "good" or "bad" doesn't matter.  It turns out they work, even though we might attempt to judge them as "bad".  I'll take "works" as more important than our judgements of "good" and "bad".  Indeed, I think our judgements of "good" and "bad" are incorrect, since Unix works and Python works.

Comment: Unless one adopts the same style and structure as builtin functions or methods I would strongly suggest avoiding adoption of 'standard' names for custom methods.  Violating implicit expectations are bad.

Answer (score 12):

If you were writing Perl, you'd essentially be duplicating [`Data::Dumper`'s functionality](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper). It takes a Perl object and turns it into a string representation that can then be used to recreate that object (essentially -- this isn't really true for blessed objects). The description of this module says it creates "**stringified** perl data structures".

Thus the process is **stringification**. That's what I've always heard it called.

Comment: I prefer to call it "dumping" an object, but your example is the best I've seen.  In Java I would override toString() for a single object or use an XLM binding library to dump a more complex tree.  The result is more often something I can paste into a spreadsheet or other tool than raw code.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I see your point about **serialize** hinting at deserializing (or is it "unserializing" ?) being the opposite, that would still be my preferred wording because it naturally implies that the process returns a string equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I'd pick something along these lines:

- toStringRep()
- createStringRepresention()
- strRep()
- toSource()
- toSourceString()

Answer (score 3):

I nominate **sourcification**.  I agree that "quine" isn't quite right, but the part where you're producing valid source code for the object seems key.

Comment: or maybe `toSourceString()`?

Comment: @Michael: That seems good for a method name, yeah.  OP seems to be asking for a general word for the concept more than method names, though.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `pickle` idea.  It quite nicely says nothing at all, leaving people seeing it asking themselves WTF and having to search for documentation and/or the implementation to figure out what client code is doing...all because of a function name that is completely random.

The guy that used to run the development team where I work liked the Master and Commander book series.  He liked to name things after the boats mentioned in those books.  I have to say that I never ceased being titillated by the cute wit it must have taken to use those names in code.  It always brought a smile to my face as I right clicked the name in VS and said, "Go to Definition," and got to wait the 20 minutes for stupisense to lock up my computer and finally take me to some random location that had nothing to do with the symbol I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The method name should say what it does, not why it does it, therefore:

`toString()` because it's how you phrased it in the title. What's done with the string afterwards (i.e whether the object can be recreated from it) is nothing to do with the method that creates the string so shouldn't influence the method name.

If you want to also have a `toString()` method that creates a human readable representation of the string you could make the other one more specific like `stringify()` to differentiate but I would only do this if necessary.

Comment: as you intuited, we will have both such methods, and there will be plenty of room for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking to output not just a string, per se, but rather a blueprint of the object.  Something that encapsulates how it behaves and all of its attributes.  You stated that this string will need to be parsed by your language interpreter, which leads me to understand that this data is being stored in a language of its own.  The language that only your language interpreter can read and write.  Given that, what's this language called?

Whatever you decide that it is called could then be used in the name to clarify what is being done.

```
myLangRepresentingObject = LanguageInterpreter->convertObjectToMyLanguage( SomeObject );
```

For example, if the string stored the objects using the language, XML, you could use something like this:

```
xmlRepresentingObject = XmlInterpreter->convertObjectToXml( SomeObject );
```

Comment: I was looking for common usage across languages. For the record, we have this problem in Python, Perl, Matlab and R.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you basically looking for a Hash() function? Where you would create a string representation of an object state that is reversible (unlike a normal hash).

Edit:I repeal the Hash() idea.How about ToSnapshot() and FromSnapshot()?

Comment: I think of 'Hash' as being irreversible.

Comment: i have to agree with your comment. The more I thought about it Hash() seemed to be more misleading than clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Encode or decode would be a a more general terminology for a bidirectional process.  You may also consider transform for a one way process.

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp this is called the **printer** and the **reader**.

Quoting the Hyperspec :

"**write, prin1, princ, print**, and **pprint** write the printed representation of object to output-stream. "

"**read** parses the printed representation of an object from input-stream and builds such an object."